# Establecer parámetros opcionales en mi ruta en Django 2.2.2

Tags: python, django

Tengo esta ruta: `path('listar/',listarEmpleados, name = 'listar'),` quiero establecerle dos parámetros opcionales y saber como llamar la ruta con cualquiera de estos parámetros establecidos.

Gracias a quien me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo los parametros requeridos se pasan por URL, los parametros opcionales se pasan por parametro GET por ejemplo `/listar?parametro_opcional=1&parametro_opcional2=2` y se lo recibe en la view asi:

```
def listarEmpleados(request):
    parametro_opcional = request.GET.get("parametro_opcional")
    parametro_opcional2 = request.GET.get("parametro_opcional2")
```

si no se manda `parametro_opcional` o `parametro_opcional2` la variable va a ser `None`.

Si lo queres llamar desde un template por ejemplo va a ser asi:

`{% url 'listar' %}?parametro_opcional=1&parametro_opcional2=2`

si queres hacerlo en una view seria asi:

`url = "%s?parametro_opcional=1&parametro_opcional2=2" % reverse("listar")`